# Cannot see my A4 size artboard in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design

I have just started with adobe illustrator and making a design in A4 size sheet but when I select it my whole page shows and the when I draw something it is not visible whereas in the navigation tab I can see my objects

[image]

I want it to look like this 
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Do your objects have a fill and stroke? A4 isn't *that* big - roughly a US letter size. But perhaps instead of inputting mm you mistakenly input some other measurement and it's not actual an A4 artboard?

Comment: View > Show Artboards?

Comment: I have edited my question. 
@ChrisBolseng Not working

Comment: Sorry must have been at the same time. Edit > Preferences > User Interface, change the canvas color? Then ctrl+0 to fit.

Comment: Tried it . 
Not working. whats wrong . I am just creating a new A4 exactly done in the tutorial

Comment: Can you draw one with the artboard tool? Your a4 should also show up with that tool selected.

Comment: @ChrisBolseng just tried that. Same thing is happening. Please help :(

Comment: @ChrisBolseng Just before closing my illustrator window I can see my objects for a sec

Comment: Solved it. Resolution issue.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> resets your zoom level to fit the artboard on the screen. Further experiment with the zoom options under 'Menu → View' and see what happens.

Comment: Not working 
please see my question I have edited it

Comment: You must be doing something wrong. Creating an A4 document then hitting CTRL+0 can only give you one result and that is showing the entire artboard.

Comment: Hi
I am doing exactly what this guy is saying https://www.webcoursesbangkok.com/blog/adobe-illustrator-tutorial/ 
Nothing different. please help

Answer (score 0):

If you've tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> and it still doesn't show up, try menu item View > Show Artboards (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>). If it says Hide Artboards, you know this is not the issue.

I recommend changing this hotkey to something you'll never press accidentally unless you use this feature.

Comment: Not Working 
Please see question again. i have edited it

Answer (score -2):

I solved it 
I was choosing HIGH resolution while creating the A4 sheet
I am sorry :P

Comment: @Lucian. This *is* the author of the question. It's a self-answer.

Comment: The resolution should not be affecting your ability to see the artboard.